# Are USB cables device-specific?

Tags: usb, compatibility, cable

I have a dozen or so USB or USB to mini-USB cables lying around. It's annoying keeping track of what goes to what.

Are they interchangeable or are they device-specific?

Does it change the answer if I'm expecting the device to transfer data vs. merely charge its battery?

For example: Can I expect the mini USB that charges a cell phone to also charge a [PS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3) controller?

Would the [Ferrite Bead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) - the cylinder on some cables - affect USB compatibility? Is that a necessary component for the functioning of its intended device?

Comment: Ferrite Beads are more for EMC/EMI and act as high frequency filters to reduce noise that could radiate from the cable. It doesn't affect compatibility.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The U means universal indeed, but some manufacturers (such as Apple) choose to provide their own proprietary USB cables -- which are not interchangeable -- while others provide **generic USB cables which are interchangeable**.

[image: diagram of standard usb connectors]

All standard USB connectors by pinout.

[image: photo of standard usb connectors]

In picture form: micro USB on the left, then mini USB, then regular full-size B and A USB.

Comment: IMO those aren't "USB" cables at all, they're a cable that happens to have one USB end.

Comment: Those are usb cables, you may wish to read the specs on the standard.  But those are different accepted standards.

Comment: Yes, the ones pictured are different forms of actual, standard, USB cables, but also yes, the proprietary ones like for the iPod are only half-USB (ie, they have a USB connector and plug into USB ports, but the other end is proprietary). There’s nothing that says that you cannot do that. For example, there are plenty of cords with a standard RCA connector on one end, and some weird, proprietary connector on the other. The same goes for power cords and pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 13):

The U in USB means Universal. They're totally interchangeable. I just keep one around and the rest as backups/to lend to others, it works pretty well.

Comment: Are there any power only cables, though?

Comment: @Nathaniel; Nope, USB is USB is USB. They can deliver power, data, or both. They're pretty universal :P

Comment: Wrong: http://www.addonics.com/products/power_adapter/usb_power_cable.asp

Comment: @Molly; Well, you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4):

They are interchangeable, but you will notice that they are not all same regarding build quality. I have a bunch of mini-USB cables, but only few of them can power a USB hard-drive without a secondary jack.

For devices not hungry for power, usually it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a new USB 3.0 standard emerging.

Here's a news story entitled [USB 3.0 - The new speed limit](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9162399/USB_3.0_The_new_speed_limit) about it I received earlier today (2010-03-02).

Answer (score 0):

Also, on occasion you will run across a cable that *looks* like a USB cable, but is really not.

The [ML-7 GPS tracker](http://www.dudek.org/blog/164) comes to mind. It has a A to mini-B USB cable that actually has a USB-to-serial converter inside the overmoulding on one end.

On the other hand, cables like that are **REALLY** rare.